Is there a known way to work out the location of an unknown device, given two or three other unknown reference points? Bluetooth on Android
Problem:
I am attempting to locate a bluetooth device. Say, earbuds. I don't know where they are.
Things I do know:

I have a general idea of the area they are in, say somewhere in a roughly 50m x 50m space.
There are at least two other bluetooth devices within the space, whose locations are also unknown, but we can assume they are somewhere within this room.

Question:
Is there a known way to determine the location of my earbuds, rough distance and direction, by using the changes in signal strengths of the three unknown locations as I move around the space?
i.e. I start in the center of the room and Unknown device A is North, I don't know this but as I travel north, the signal strength for A increases sharply. Unknown Device B maybe is northeast, and as I travel north, its signal increases but at a proportionately slower rate than signalA. Conversely, the earbuds signal strength drops, suggesting that they are in fact somewhere to the south of the starting point. If I travel south, A decreases, B decreases more slowly, and earbuds increase.
Does anyone know of a way to attempt to estimate distance and direction this way using the signal strengths of devices as one moves around a space?
Edit
I want to add the constraint that I do not want to use any external multi-antenna arrays or devices that are specifically tooled to BT direction-finding. I want to use a common internal omnidirectional BT antenna such as within an unmodified smartphone like an iPhone 12-15+ Or Samsung S21-23+ or Google Pixel 5,6-9+

There is triangulation, but it doesn't work quite like that.  In triangulation in 2 dimensions (we'll assume no z axis), you need 3 known locations not in a line, and a signal strength from each to the unknown device.  Then you can use that signal strength to figure out the location.
A     B
    X
  C

Let's say you know the signal strength from A to X is 100db.  That may translate into 100m. You won't know the direction, but you know it's 100m away, so you know it's on a circle around A with a radius of 100m, but it could be anywhere on that circle.  If you also know the strength from B is 50m, you know its also on a circle of radius 50 from B.  Those 2 circles would intersect at 2 points.  You know X is at one of those two.  If you know the strength is 10m from C, you'd know its were all 3 circles intersect, which would be a single point.  (In reality due to noise and the nature of signals, there would really be narrow rings instead of perfect circles and you'd have a small odd shape around X) (Adding a z axis requires 1 more known point non-coplanar to the other 3).
A more normal use for this is for the device X itself to figure out where it is from knowing where A, B, and C are.  This can be used for ultra precise locations beyond what GPS can do, or for places GPS doesn't work.  Its normal for A. B. and C to be BLE beacon devices, in which case they emit a signal (usually an ID so you can tell them apart) and X does the calculation.  But you could reverse that if X is actively broadcasting, and have A, B, and C communicate to locate X.
Of course for this to work to find X, you'd need X to be broadcasting frequently.  Which means it will only work on a cooperating device, not a random device thrown into the space.  And since you need to know A, B, and C you need a prepared space.
Now if you don't have a prepared space and want to do this-  as long as X is broadcasting you can get distance.  Just not direction.  If X is stationary, you could then find it by playing hot and cold.
Of course for all of this you'll be limited by the distance the radio broadcasts.  That's about 10m for bluetooth, and maybe 400m for wifi.  And any obstacles like walls, trees, people, etc as well as atmospheric conditions will effect accuracy of the distance calculation.  You'd probably want to do day of calibrations if you need accuracy.  Although if you just want to do the hotter colder thing that's not necessary.
